# How to change a standard alert message for FormControl type="email"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

How to change a standard alert message of FormControl of type="email", for the need of adaption to a different language?

-So this is my code:

```js
<FormGroup controlId="createAccountLastName" >
    <Col sm={2}>
        Prezime:
    </Col>
    <Col sm={5}>
        <FormControl inputRef={inputLastName => this.inputLastName = inputLastName}  type="text" placeholder="Prezime" />
    </Col>
</FormGroup>
```

-And my alert message that is always poping up, when I submit the form and I wrongly structure email is:

[image]

-I want to change that message to a message in my native language? How to override it?

Comment: that's provided by the browser.

Comment: Is there a way to write our own alert?

Comment: theres plenty of validation frameworks out there

Comment: I see ok thank you!